# How can I run my .app from my server and have the wrong version?

Tags: macos, scripting, applescript, compatibility, macos-sierra

I have an AppleScript script that I saved as a .app file and I am simply moves directories in the correct location.  The script works perfectly when on my local machine but when I upload it to my server and download from my server (trying to create the user experience) then the script has has a circle and a line running through it with this error:

*"You can’t use this version of the application “myapp” with this version of macOS.  You have macOS 10.12.3. The application requires macOS 2573.6 or later."*

I tried googling macOS 2573.6 and nothing comes up and I have no idea what that is.  I don't even think that is a real macOS version.  If anyone has any idea how to fix this issue I would be extremely grateful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are likely breaking all kinds of attributes in the App Bundle during the transfer.

Compress the app bundle first, then copy that to the server. Then, to test, re-download that archive and uncompress it locally.

It should run.